# How to run a python function after updating the argument?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a function that takes a value as an argument. I want to run the function with a given argument for 2 seconds and then run the function with an updated argument value with the rest of the process. For example,

```
try:
    drop(20)
    sleep(2)
    drop(90)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
```

But this code is not working, the function is only taking the value '20', not updating to the value '90' after two seconds.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.